# syntax error list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there be questions with syntax error on this but I can not figure the problem here. Why is it given me the syntax error below?

Update: Now getting syntax error at line 55
    Module = namedtuple('Module', 'code title ects')

```
BB1_MODULES = {
              'BB103': Module('BB103', 'Computer Systems', 5),
              'BB111': Module('BB111', 'Web Design', 5),
              'BB112': Module('BB112', 'Digital Innovation', 5),
              'BB123': Module('BB123', 'Computer Programming I', 10),
              'BB124': Module('BB124', 'Computer Programming II', 10),
              'BB343': Module('BB343', 'Networks and Internet', 5),
              'BB434': Module('BB434', 'Operating Systems', 5),
              'BB543': Module('BB543', 'Problem Solving', 5),
              'BB432': Module('BB432', 'IT Mathematics', 10)}#ects

class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, idnum, surname, firstname, mods=CA1_MODULES):
        self.__idnum = idnum
        self.__surname = surname
        self.__firstname = firstname
        self.__mods = mods
        self.__marks = {code: 0 for code in self.__mods.keys()} #returm a list of module codes #dict comprehension
        # self.__total_credits
        self.__total__credits = sum[mod.ects for mod in self.__mods.values()]
    def __str__(self):
        name = '{} : {} {}'.format(self.__idnum,
                                   self.__firstname,
                                   self.__surname)
        uline = '-' * len(name)
        results =  '\n'.join([code + ' : ' + self.__mods[code].title +
                              ' : ' + str(self.__marks[code])
                              for code in sorted(self.__mods.keys())])
        pm = 'Precision mark: {:.2f}'.format(self.precision_mark())
        if self.passed():
            outcome = 'Pass'
        elif self.passed_by_compensation():
            outcome = 'Pass by compensation'
        else:
            outcome = 'Fail'

        return '\n'.join([name, uline, results, pm, outcome])

    def add_mark(self, module, mark):
        self.__marks[module]=mark

    def precision_mark():
        [self.__marks[mod] * self.__mods[code].ects for code in self.__mods.keys()] / self.__total_credits

    def passed():
        return min(self__marks.values()) >= 40

    def passed_by_compensation():
        if self.precision_mark() <45:
            return False
        sum([self.__mods[code].ects for code in self.__mods.keys() if self.marks[code] < 40]) > self.__total_credits / 6:
            return False
        return min(self.marks.__values()) >= 35

self.__total__credits = sum[mod.ects for mod in self.__mods.values()]
                                       ^
#SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#self.__total__credits = sum[mod.ects for mod in self.__mods.values()]
```

Comment: You have missing parent `sum([mod.ects for mod in self.__mods.values()])` or `sum(mod.ects for mod in self.__mods.values())`

Answer (score 4):

`sum`is a function, you thus have to use it with brackets:

```
self.__total__credits = sum([mod.ects for mod in self.__mods.values()])
```

Comment: now i get syntax error at:                                            sum([self.__mods[code].ects for code in #self.__mods.keys() if self.marks[code] < 40]) > self.__total_credits / 6:
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you forgot the `if` statement at the beggining of the line…